# Code for syncing Google Sheets with Calendars

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I am trying to get a google sheet to provide details of events for a calendar.

So far I have got it syncing.

Where I am currently struggling is

1. Auto Sync so that when a new event is added to the sheet it will upload to the sheet (doesn't need to be immediate can by at set times during a day). As current manual sync just repeats events too so would need to limit that once an event it added it isn't added again
2. Event editing and deletion
3. Variable recurrences, most are weekly but have a few monthly ones and some that would be fortnightly/3 weekly.

Here is my current script (calendar id removed)

```
const calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("");

function createevent(e){
  // Creates an event series
  calendar.createEventSeries(e.group,
    e.start,
    e.stop,
    CalendarApp.newRecurrence()
        .addWeeklyRule()
        .until(new Date(e.termend))
        )
    
}

function churchGroup() {
  
  // Set up sheet and calendar
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Events');
  var events = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  events.shift()
  var fn=function(x){
    var e={
            group:x[1],
            start:x[18],
            stop:x[19],
            termend:x[11]
            }
  createevent(e)
  }

  events.forEach(fn)

}
```

EDIT:

I have used the above script to link a google sheet and a calander so that it creates events automatically for me from the data in a sheet similar to this one

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cTlx30JdMrR_8DwewncPmS0nwDLVd6tcVOtjU8Rr_eE/edit?usp=drivesdk

I can not legally share the original document as that contains customer information.

What I need to get the script to now do is automatically update the calander when an event is added, deleted or edited.

I also want it to identify if an event is held weekly, fortnightly, monthly. Just now that uploads all events every week which is not great as that creates events when there is not an event on.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can I ask you about the detail of your question? For example, can you provide the sample input and output situations as the image?

Comment: I'll edit my post

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. About `What I need to get the script to now do is automatically update the calander when an event is added, deleted or edited.`, in this case, where do you want to put them from and to? And I cannot understand `I also want it to identify if an event is held weekly, fortnightly, monthly. Just now that uploads all events every week which is not great as that creates events when there is not an event on.`.